How to setup CDN for whole website, not just static resources?
I have complex question. Is it possible to serve whole static website via CDN (not just css, js, images... but also rendered HTML views). No matter which CDN provider I tried, I can't get it to work because this is where DNS and nginx settings come into game. Let's describe this using Amazon Cloudfront.

I have configured cloudfront for custom origin let's say example.com
example.com is hosted elsewhere on different provider than amazon and serve content via nginx
DNS provider is amazon, so I can create A record alias to cloudfront distribution
I have configured nginx to allow just https and non-www version of website, which means I redirect http://example.com to https://example.com, http://www.example.com to https://example.com, https://www.example.com to https://example.com
My DNS records looks like this:

A record for www points to IP of that remote server
A record for root domain (@) points to cloudfront url in format xxxxxxx.cloudfront.net via alias



Here comes the problem:

My site is fully accessible via xxxxxxx.cloudfront.net : which means any path I try that works (for example xxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/en/blog) returns the correct content.
but my DNS root record, which is alias for xxxxxxx.cloudfront.net does not work, because if visitor tryies to visit example.com, which points him in the background to CDN cached endpoint on xxxxxxx.cloudfront.net, amazon tries to visit example.com to collect response and cached it, but amazon don't know where to go, because root A record does not point to IP addres of that remote server but it points to amazon CDN which couses error 403.

So my question is:
Is it possible to configure nginx on that remote server somehow to return a content, when the request comes from amazon (to cache it) and when the request does not come from amazon (some visitor), then points him to CDN (xxxxxxx.cloudfront.net)? This rule must work, because in opposite way, if visitor comes to domain (for example example.com/en/blog) and amazon does not have cached response for this request, it will points him to remote server, which will handle that request, return response which amazon will cache and next time visitor visits same path, amazon now does not need to call the remote server, he just return cashed response until expires.
But I don't know how to set-up that nginx and DNS in Route 53 correctly to work in this way.

Resolved by adding third origin - for example production.example.com, where will amazon cloudfront connect to and root domain and also www domain connected to cloudfront.
Must fixed URL generation at origin production.example.com to return https://example.com/* and not https://production.example.com/* or using relative path of resources and hreflinks
